# Should i pass unique OVERLAPPED structure for each WSASend call , in this case?

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a list of sockets.(Opened connections)

I have n worker threads.

Thread loop:

```
while (1)
    {
        _this.result = GetQueuedCompletionStatus(a_server.server_iocp, &_this.numberOfBytesTransfered,
            &_this.completionKey, (OVERLAPPED**)&_this.iocp_task, INFINITE);
  ...
}
```

I have this simple struct:

```
struct iocp_send_global :public iocp_task<IOCP_SEND_GLOBAL> {
  OVERLLAPED ov; //overlapped struct at top
  std::atomic_uint32_t ref;

bool decr_ref(){ return ref.fetch_sub(1, std::memory_order_acq_rel) == 1;}


//packet data here
}

...
```

This is the 'Broadcast' function:

```
iocp_send_global * packet = new iocp_send_global;

[set packet data here]

for(int i=0;i<connectionsCount;++i){
    WSASend(connections[i],...,&packet,...); //posting same packet to all connections
}
```

I want to do this in the worker loop after GetQueuedCompletionStatus call returns with the overlapped result;

```
    if (_this.iocp_task->type == IOCP_SEND_GLOBAL) {
                    auto* task = (iocp_send_global*)_this.iocp_task;

                    if (!task->decr_ref()) {
                        _this.iocp_task = nullptr;
                        //dont delete the task yet, 
                        //all send post must finish first 
                        //[all posts share the same buffer]
                    }
                    else {
                    //delete the task containing the send data after all send posts finished
                       delete _this.iocp_task;
                       _this.iocp_task = nullptr;
                    }

}
```

From what i read on Microsoft WSASend documentation each WSASend overlapped call sould have its own OVERLAPPED structure passed, but is that valid when i WSASend the same buffer?

Thank you!

Comment: only if you not care about return status and numberOfBytesTransfered (and exactly know on which socket io finished) you can use the same `OVERLAPPED` buffer in multiple requests). if properly implement addref/release logic on this structure

Comment: Duude, thanks, i dont care about thouse things. And its decr_ref only, when i post the send i set the ref to the no. of connections

Comment: Post it as a Answare please so i can accept it!

Comment: you need clear understand for what `OVERLAPPED` is used. this is storage for `IO_STATUS_BLOCK` where stored result of operation and additional information (usually numberOfBytesTransfered). if use the same `OVERLAPPED` in several IO requests - this information will be undefined (overwritten multiple time). so usual it must be unique per operation. also it let pointer to additional information(say point to socket) however if you not care and not need all this - formal you can use and the same `OVERLAPPED` - minimal requirements - memory mast be valid until last operation is finished

Comment: and in your code invisible how you increment (addref) reference to structure before `WSASend` and not check it result.

Comment: and use you the the same buffer or no - this is absolute no matter. system simply save pointer to your `OVERLAPPED` when io begin (in `IRP`) and when operation end - update data in `OVERLAPPED` (status,information). for not standard use it - need good understand how this work internal

Comment: the only disadvantage i see here is that i cant see if the operation failed [noOfBytesTransfered == 0]

Comment: I found the solution, since os uses a queue for the operations , i will do the fallowing, i will hold a array of indexes of connection to send to, a remainingToSendCount, and after each opCompleted i decrement remainingToSendCount and i repost the send clearing the overlapped , the target connection is connections[remainingToSendCount] , if remainingToSendCount < 0  done , the sends are done, can delete the packet with the overlaped and all.

Comment: this way i can close dead connections to :D

Comment: main - understand how `OVERLAPPED` used/worked in io operation. based on this you already can select solution. however i think this not good solution. you need have some context( structure) per socket(where you say store socket handle, `remainingToSendCount` etc). and per every io operation allocated packet which containing `OVERLAPPED`, operation type, and back pointer to socket structure. and in general `1201ProgramAlarm` answer is correct

Comment: duuude!!! my struct has the OVERLAPPED struct at the begining, i instanciate my struct which has the overlapped at top, so the pointer to my struct points to an overlapped struct and additional data i know about, the os needs the overlapped, when i get the result i cast the pointer back to my struct, and goood!

Comment: you have need 2 absolute different structures. one associated with socket - where data related to socked (handle, state) and another associated with every io operation (containing `OVERLAPPED`, operation code and pointer to first structure (per socket)) this is most native and reliable way

Comment: dude, i have struct connection{ SOCKET sock; ....}; static connection Connections[SERVER_MAX_CONNECTIONS]; and this, template<IOCPTaskType  T>struct iocp_task { OVERLAPPED ov ;int type =T;}; and this one struct send_global:public iocp_task<IOCP_SEND_GLOBAL> {uint8* buffer; WSABUFF wsaBuff; uint32* connectionIndexes;uint32 toSendRemainingCount; ...};

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must pass a different `OVERLAPPED` buffer for each call since you'll be making multiple pending calls.  This is clearly spelled out in the documentation for the `OVERLAPPED` structure.